# Writing pixel values from pgm file to text file with latitude, longitude and depth in Perl

Tags: perl, pgm

I am very new to Perl and have not much idea about how to go about doing this.

I have come across some code that reads a .pgm file named `SeaWiFS_median_depth.35N.35S.180W.180E.pgm` and rescales some of the pixel values in the file into latitudes, longitudes and depths and prints them on screen when I run the script.

```
my $depth_file = 'SeaWiFS_median_depth.35N.35S.180W.180E.pgm';

open F,$depth_file or die "Could not open $depth_file ($!)";

<F>;    # skip header line
my($wid,$hgt) = split ' ',scalar <F>;
<F>;    # skip another header line

$wid == 36000 or die "Unexpected width in depth file\n";
$hgt ==  7000 or die "Unexpected height in depth file\n";

my $inc = 360/$wid;

my $log500 = log(100/0.2);

for($lat = 35 - $inc/2; $lat > -35; $lat -= $inc){
  for($lon = -180 + $inc/2; $lon < 180; $lon += $inc){

    read(F,$pixel,1) == 1 or die "Error reading $depth_file ($!)";
    $pixel = unpack "C",$pixel;

    printf "%7.3f %8.3f ",$lat,$lon;

    if($pixel == 0){
      print "no data\n";
    }
    elsif($pixel == 1){
      print "land\n";
    }
    elsif($pixel == 255){
      print "cloud or other masking condition\n";
    }
    else{
      $depth = 0.2*exp($log500*($pixel - 2)/252);
      printf "%6.2f\n",$depth;  # depth in meters
    }
  }
}
```

However, what i am want to do is to write the values printed on screen - latitude, longitude and depth to a text (tab delimited) or csv file so I can use it in another program like R or a GIS software package to do further analysis.

Can someone please help me out here please?

Comment: `/path/to/script > /path/to/output/file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You can either direct the the output of the script into a file
with the '>>' operator.
Use it like this: `perl /your/script.pl > /your/text/file.txt`
If you want to create a new file on the fly, use '>>'.
`perl /your/script.pl >> /your/text/file.txt`

Your second Option is to open a Filehandle in Perl like this:
`open my $fh, ">>", "/yout/text/file.txt" or die "Failed to open file: $!";`.
Add this line below the first `open` statement.

This creates the file you want to write in.
To print content into the file, add the filehandle (`$fh`)
to the `print` statement like this:
`printf $fh "%6.2f\n",$depth;  # depth in meters`

To manipulate the delimeter of the your data, replace the `\n` (which is 
a linebreak) with the one you want (`\t` is for tab).

Full Perl example:

```
my $depth_file = 'SeaWiFS_median_depth.35N.35S.180W.180E.pgm';

open F,$depth_file or die "Could not open $depth_file ($!)";
open my $fh, ">>", "/yout/text/file.txt" or die "Failed to open file: $!";


<F>;    # skip header line

my($wid,$hgt) = split ' ',scalar <F>;

<F>;    # skip another header line

$wid == 36000 or die "Unexpected width in depth file\n";
$hgt ==  7000 or die "Unexpected height in depth file\n";

my $inc = 360/$wid;

my $log500 = log(100/0.2);

for($lat = 35 - $inc/2; $lat > -35; $lat -= $inc){
  for($lon = -180 + $inc/2; $lon < 180; $lon += $inc){

    read(F,$pixel,1) == 1 or die "Error reading $depth_file ($!)";
    $pixel = unpack "C",$pixel;

    printf "%7.3f %8.3f ",$lat,$lon;

    if($pixel == 0){
      print "no data\t";
    }
    elsif($pixel == 1){
      print "land\t";
    }
    elsif($pixel == 255){
      print "cloud or other masking condition\t";
    }
    else{
      $depth = 0.2*exp($log500*($pixel - 2)/252);
      printf $fh "%6.2f\t",$depth;  # depth in meters
    }
  }
  print $fh, "\n"; # new line after each line of the image
}
```